# How to edit the DeNoise parameters for all cut parts of a clip?

Tags: premiere, noise

I'm a newbie in video editing. I wanted to apply DeNoise filter in Adobe Premier Pro 2020, so I did so. Then I went on cutting parts of my clip, to jump cut parts of the footage.

Then I realized that I have to reduce the DeNoise level. So I did so for a cut part. Now I see that other parts do not change. And also when I cut a new part of the footage, new part has the old level and new level is not applied to it.

So I have two questions:

1. How to set DeNoise properties for all cut parts of a footage?
2. How to make Premier understand that this new level is the default level and when I cut another part, it should obey this new settings?

Answer (score 2):

If you need to apply the same effect to a whole clip, you can use Master Clip effects:

https://helpx.adobe.com/premiere-pro/using/master-clip-effects.html

That way, you apply it to the file, and any clips from that file that you place into a sequence will have the same effect applied.  If you need to adjust it, you only need to do it once to the master effect.